# Rickshaw RangeSlider - Zoom in by default

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

I am looking at a simple Rickshaw chart with data from a JSON file.

```
d3.json(data, function(error, json) {

var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
                element: document.getElementById(chart_id),
                renderer: 'line',
                series: [
                         {name: 'myseries',
                          data: json[0].data}
                          ]
                })
graph.render();
});
```

I would like to access the `graph` after it has been rendered. Since the graph is created within a callback function I cannot simply return the handle. Also  `document.getElementById(chart_id)` does not have a chart attribute.

My goal is to, for example, allow users to specify a certain range for multiple charts at the same time (e.g. last 5 years) without having to adjust the RangeSlider for each one of them. With access to the chart I could then do

```
new_rng = [new_min,new_max]
graph.window.xMin = new_rng[0]
graph.window.xMax = new_rng[1]
$('#' + slider_id).slider('option', 'values',new_rng)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you declare the variable outside the callback and assign within?

Comment: Thanks for your response Lars. I would like to be able to change to a different time span (e.g. last 3 years) without reloading the data for the graph. See this [yahoo chart](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=EURUSD%3DX+Interactive#symbol=;range=2y;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a similar problem to the one I encountered with a xively feed where the data is not returned when the graph is rendered. Here's my post.

[Multiple calls to xively.feed.history()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261461/multiple-calls-to-xively-feed-history/20427544#20427544)